# What Is the Use of the Random Characters in the Query String Section of a URL to a CSS File?

Tags: css

I often see URLs in the following format:

```
revslider/rs-plugin/css/settings.css?nzs0qa
```

What does the query string `?nzs0qa` mean?

Comment: This would most likely be a hash of the file, which is different whenever the contents of the file change. This prevents problems with caching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nzs0qa is a ramdom string. The purpose of the "?nzs0qa" is to force your browser to download the latest version of the css. You know browser will keep the static files such as css, js, etc in cache. If you update the css, but your visitors use old version, it might be some mistake.

That's all.

Comment: ok thanks, then we can generate the string using php but css has nothing to do with that ?

Comment: Yes, this random string is generated by PHP/C#/JAVA. If you use PHP, you can use:
revslider/rs-plugin/css/settings.css?nzs0qa<?php echo random_string; ?>

Answer (score 0):

The part of the question mark is called the `query` part. The question mark itself is not part of the query.

I suggest reading about URL format.
From Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator

> An optional query, separated from the preceding part by a question mark (?), containing a query string of non-hierarchical data. Its syntax is not well defined, but by convention is most often a sequence of attribute–value pairs separated by a delimiter.